# Multiple actions when a when clause is satisfied in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In `pyspark`, I know that the `when` clause can have multiple conditions to result in a single output like so:

```
df.withColumn(
  'Output', 
  when(
    (condition1==True) & (condition2==True), 
    do_something)
  .otherwise(do_something_else)
)
```

But is it possible to perform multiple outputs when a condition is satisfied? Like so:

```
df.when(
    condition1==True, withColumn('This', lit("yes")) 
    & withColumn('That', lit("also yes")))
  .otherwise(
    withColumn('This', lit("no")) 
    & withColumn('That', lit("also no"))
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by creating a **`struct`** in your **`when/otherwise`** clause. You can **`name and create as many fields inside your struct`** and expand them by **`colname.*`** as shown below.

```
df.show() #sample dataframe
#+-----+------+
#|Sales|Region|
#+-----+------+
#| 5000|    US|
#| 2500|    IN|
#| 4500|    AU|
#| 4500|    NZ|
#+-----+------+

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("col", F.when(F.col("Region")=='US',\
                            F.struct(F.lit("yes").alias("This"),F.lit("also yes").alias("That")))\
                      .otherwise(F.struct(F.lit("no").alias("This"),F.lit("also no").alias("That"))))\
                      .select(*df.columns,"col.*")\
                      .show()

#+-----+------+----+--------+
#|Sales|Region|This|    That|
#+-----+------+----+--------+
#| 5000|    US| yes|also yes|
#| 2500|    IN|  no| also no|
#| 4500|    AU|  no| also no|
#| 4500|    NZ|  no| also no|
#+-----+------+----+--------+
```